# Total boundedness for a non standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I want to prove this two things:

1)  $(\mathbb{R},d_B)$ is not totally bounded.

where $d_B=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ and $d_E$ is the Euclidean metric.

2)  $B_M(0)$ is totally bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For the first one, we know that every norm in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are equivalent so  $(\mathbb{R},d_B)$ is homeomorphic to  $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ so If we assume that $ (\mathbb{R},d_B)$ is totally bounded, then so is  $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ but we know that this is not even bounded, so the result follows.

Well I think that the norm that induce that metric is $$\frac{||x||}{1+||x||}$$ where $||x||=\sqrt{|x^{2}|}$

Am I right?, and if it wrong can you help me to fix it please?

For two, I don't how to prove it, my definition of totally bounded is the following:

> For every $\varepsilon>0$  there exists a finite set of points $x_1,\dots,x_n\in A$ such that $A=\cup_{i=1}^n B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)$, where $B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)$ denotes the open $\varepsilon$-ball with center $x_i$.

So I have to pick an arbitrary $\varepsilon$ and give general points to bound the ball of radius $M$.

Can someone help me with that verification and the part two please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, that doesn't work, because you don't know that $d_B$ is induced by a norm. In fact it is not, because all norms on positive dimensional spaces are unbounded, but that metric is bounded. (I might edit if you post an attempt and show where you get stuck.)

For #2, one open cover that you always have of a set $A$ in a metric space is

$$\{ B_\epsilon(x) : x \in A \}.$$

Now use compactness to get a finite subcover.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :), so How can I fix 1?, and for 2 why do I use compactness?

Comment: @user162343 You don't have to use compactness, but this is an easy way to do it. You could also do it explicitly, if you want.

Comment: Well the ball I am talking about is not closed :(

Comment: @user162343 That's not a problem: a cover of the closed ball is a cover of the open cover.

Comment: mmmm I dont understand this last comment :)

Comment: @user162343 So you have an uncountable open cover of the closed ball. You extract a finite subcover using the fact that the closed ball is compact. This subcover is also a cover of the open ball.

Comment: So what could be a finite subcover of the one you posted?, The thing is that my definition only contempletes the fact that we get equal radius :)

Comment: @user162343 If you just want to prove existence, you don't have to write down what the subcover is. It must exist by compactness.

Comment: But that subcover should hold the requirements

Comment: Well I think that the norm that induce that metric is $$\frac{||x||}{1+||x||}$$ where $||x||=\sqrt{|x^{2}|}$

Comment: @user162343 Your proposed norm is not a norm, in particular it is not homogeneous. Homogeneity is the easiest way to prove that the metric induced by a norm is always unbounded, except in the zero dimensional case. And it is easy to see that your metric is bounded.

Comment: jajaja right :) but then how can I fix this?

Comment: @user162343 Two hints: $d_B$ is a bounded metric which induces the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. (There is probably a more direct way to proceed, but this does work.)

Comment: We haven't seen that result yet :(, the compactness one

Comment: Fair enough. Another possibility: can you argue that every ball with respect to $d_B$ is also a ball with respect to $d_E$? Which ball is it?

Comment: Yes I can argue that, and the balls in the bounded metric are intervals right ?

Comment: @user162343 Right. (I keep saying "ball" partly because everything we're saying here would go through the same if $\mathbb{R}$ were $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: Ok :) so since balls are the same in both spaces,( because they are homeomorphic ) we have that the intervals should be totally bounded but they are not because the could be not bounded even, right?

Comment: @user162343 Total boundedness isn't a topological notion by itself. You should work out what the correspondence between the balls is. That is, the $B$ ball of radius $r$ is the $E$ ball of radius what?

Comment: Well they are intervals in both spaces, and particularly we say that (n,n+1) is totally bounded but as n goes to infinity it is not bounded so it could not  be totally bounded :) Is this right ?

Comment: You misunderstand. Let me work through the step that I meant. If you have a ball of radius $r_B$ in $d_B$, where $0<r_B<1$, then it is the same as a ball of radius $r_E$ in $d_E$, where $\frac{r_E}{1+r_E}=r_B$. Solve this equation for $r_E$ and then think about the result.

Comment: Ok :) let me check give a while :)

Comment: So I got that $r_E=\frac{r_B}{1-r_B}$ and as $r_B$ goes to 1 it is unbounded right? Or...

Comment: @user162343 The key is the other way: what happens at small distances? For, say, $r_B \leq 1/2$, $r_E \leq 2 r_B$. Thus if you have a $\epsilon$-net for $d_B$ and $\epsilon \leq 1/2$, then you have a $2\epsilon$-net for $d_E$. But $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ is definitely not totally bounded.

Comment: So, let me put everything we have done , we say let assume that our space is totally bounded so we know that R with the euclidean metric is homeomorphic to the one with the bounded one, so balls are the same in both spaces , therefore we take a ball with radius $r_B$ in the bounded space then the radius in the euclidean is the one that we have compute so in small distantes it does not work because ... I didnt understand that parta :)

Comment: Don't mess with the topology part, that doesn't help so much with this way of writing the proof. The point is that if $(\mathbb{R},d_B)$ has a $\epsilon$-net for $\epsilon \leq 1/2$, then $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ has a $2 \epsilon$-net. Why does this imply that if $(\mathbb{R},d_B)$ is totally bounded then so is $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$?

Comment: Because this is saying that given an epsilon for the bounded space we only take 2epsilon for the total boundess of the euclidean space so we get that all the euclidean space is totally bounded but it is not even bounded :) right ?

Comment: Pretty much. That's a bit confusingly worded, but I think you have the idea.

Comment: Well jajajaja , then what would be the best way of saying it :) ?

Comment: "Suppose $(\mathbb{R},d_B)$ is totally bounded, i.e. for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\epsilon$-net for $(\mathbb{R},d_B)$. Then [by the preceding calculation] for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $2 \epsilon$-net for $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$. Since $2 \epsilon$ can still be made arbitrarily small, we conclude that $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ is bounded". Or something like this.

Comment: Right Jajajajajajajaja, and for the second one, what can be done ?

Comment: My sketch for the second one is essentially complete.

Comment: But the thing is that you are fixing the point and not the radius as is require right ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If we're still talking about the second question, I gave an open cover of the closed ball made up of balls of radius $\epsilon$; it has a finite subcover; this subcover is a $\epsilon$-net for the closed ball, and hence also for the open ball.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay, but the thing is that in my definition it says that, given $\epsilon$ I have to find points $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ such that I can cover my space, and the cover that you give me the radius vary, and the point is fixed :(

Comment: Read the definition I gave for the cover again. The radius is fixed at $\epsilon$, while initially the center varies among all points in $A$. Then we take only finitely many of them afterward. (Maybe our notation differs; for me $B_\epsilon(x) = \{ y \in A : d(x,y) < \epsilon \}$.)

Comment: One more doubt, How do you know that all the points in the closed ball are in the open ball?, I have this doubt because, Imagine that you have the finite subcover of the closed ball, the the balls of the cover (the ones of radius epsilon) are about points of the closed ball, How do you ensure that they are points of the open ball ?

Comment: It might help to know whether your definition of total boundedness is relative to an ambient space, or only in the metric space in question. If it is relative to an ambient space, then there is no problem. If not, then you are right, some of the centers of the balls that I gave will be "on the boundary", which will require some correction to get an appropriate cover. Here's a suggestion for the modification: if you have a ball at center $Mx$ and radius $\epsilon$, replace it with a ball at center $(M-\epsilon/2)x$ and radius $2 \epsilon$.

Comment: So I can only write your suggestion as a comment right? :)

Comment: If you don't have an ambient space then yes, what I wrote doesn't actually make any sense as is, so don't write it as is. (For my last comment you should also be careful to ensure that $M$ is large enough that it works out.)

Comment: Ok :) but I didn't understand that last comment :), and how should I write it then?

Comment: Draw a picture in the plane. You have a big disk $D_1$ and a little disk $D_2$ whose center is on $\partial D_1$. You define $D_3$ whose radius is twice that of $D_2$ and whose center is a little bit closer to the center of $D_1$ (and in particular is in the interior of $D_1$). Then I claim that $D_2 \subset D_3$. Do you see why? Do you see why you don't need $n=2$ for this?

Comment: Let me check it out this :) give a while please :)